# Form Validation and Alert issues in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms, function, validation

The following is a complete copy of the project I'm working on. I'm having problems with the JavaScript validating segments of the form as well as JavaScript producing an alert at the end of the function.

The idea is to have the functions is to validate the form so that, if you are over 18: you only need the first and last name fields filled out. (The content doesn't really matter so long as it works.) On the other hand however, if you are under 18, the function will need to validate guardian details as well.

Until somewhat recent changes were made however this worked fine, the problem is I left the project for several weeks so I don't know what changes were made to be able to undo them. Ideally the basic code wouldn't change too much, I'm looking for a quick fix or stop-gap measures that will have the same effect.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Work Field Trip Registration</title>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function HideReveal() {

                    if (document.getElementById("YesNo").selectedIndex == "1") {
                        document.getElementById("ifYes").style.display = "block";
                        Required();
                        //alert('1st Option Tested');
                    }
                    else if (document.getElementById("YesNo").selectedIndex == "0") {
                        document.getElementById("ifYes").style.display = "none";
                        Required();
                        //alert('2nd Option Tested');
                    }
                    }

                    function Required() {

                    if (document.getElementById("YesNo").selectedIndex == "1") {
                        AddRequirement();
                        //alert("Step1");
                    }

                    else {
                        NoRequirement();
                        //alert("Step2");
                    }
                    }
                    function NoRequirement() {

                    document.getElementById("GuardName").removeAttribute("required");
                    document.getElementById("GuardPhone").removeAttribute("required");
                        //alert("Step3");
                    }

                    function AddRequirement() {

                    document.forms("death")("GuardianName").setAttribute("required", "");
                    document.forms("death")("GuardianNumber").setAttribute("required", "");
                        //alert("Step4");
                    }

                    function validateForm() {

                    var a = document.forms("death")("GuardianName").value;
                    var b = document.forms("death")("GuardianNumber").value;
                    var c = document.forms("death")("FirstName").value;
                    var d = document.forms("death")("LastName").value;

                        if (document.getElementById("YesNo").selectedIndex == "1")
                        {
                            if (a == "" || b == "") {
                                alert("Please fill ALL required fields");
                            }

                            else {
                                alert("Registration Complete!");    
                            }
                        }

                        else if (c == "" || d == "") {
                                alert("Please fill ALL required fields")
                        }

                        else {
                            alert("Registration Complete!")
                        }

                    }
                </script>
        </head>

    <body>
        <h2>Work Field Trip Registration!</h2>
        <h4>Please enter your details.</h4>
        <form name="death">
                First Name:<br>
            <input required type="text" name="FirstName"><br>
                Last Name:<br>
            <input required type="text" name="LastName"><br>
                Gender:<br>
                <select name="dMenu">
                    <option>Male</option>
                    <option>Female</option>
                </select><br><br>
                Are you under 18?
                <select id="YesNo" onChange="HideReveal()" name="dMenu">
                    <option name="OptionNo" id="OptionNo" value="0">No</option>
                    <option name="OptionYes" id="OptionYes" value="1">Yes</option>
                </select><br><br>
        <div id="ifYes" style="display:none">
            Please enter your Parent/Guardian's name:<br>
            <input type="text" id="GuardName" name="GuardianName"><br>
            Please enter your Parent/Guardian's phone number:<br>
            <input type="text" id="GuardPhone" name="GuardianNumber"><br>
        </div>
            <input onClick="validateForm()" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I apologise for the Questions formatting. I'm not used to Stack Overflow and how to set elements and segments out yet.

Answer (score 0):

1) you don't need to call validate if you already set field to required. The browser will handle that for you.
2. I wonder why you used 'getElementbyId' in NoRequirement() but document.forms in AddRequirement(). 
In anycase here is a modified version of your code. cheers

```
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Work Field Trip Registration</title>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function HideReveal() {

                    if (document.getElementById("YesNo").selectedIndex == "1") {
                        document.getElementById("ifYes").style.display = "block";
                        Required();
                        //alert('1st Option Tested');
                    }
                    else if (document.getElementById("YesNo").selectedIndex == "0") {
                        document.getElementById("ifYes").style.display = "none";
                        Required();
                        //alert('2nd Option Tested');
                    }
                    }

                    function Required() {

                    if (document.getElementById("YesNo").selectedIndex == "1") {
                        AddRequirement();
                        //alert("Step1");
                    }

                    else {
                        NoRequirement();
                        //alert("Step2");
                    }
                    }
                    function NoRequirement() {

                    document.getElementById("GuardName").removeAttribute("required");
                    document.getElementById("GuardPhone").removeAttribute("required");
                        //alert("Step3");
                    }

                    function AddRequirement() {

                        document.getElementById('GuardName').setAttribute("required","")
                        document.getElementById('GuardPhone').setAttribute("required","")

                        //alert("Step4");
                    }


                </script>
        </head>

    <body>
        <h2>Work Field Trip Registration!</h2>
        <h4>Please enter your details.</h4>
        <form name="death">
                First Name:<br>
            <input required type="text" name="FirstName"><br>
                Last Name:<br>
            <input required type="text" name="LastName"><br>
                Gender:<br>
                <select name="dMenu">
                    <option>Male</option>
                    <option>Female</option>
                </select><br><br>
                Are you under 18?
                <select id="YesNo" onChange="HideReveal()" name="dMenu">
                    <option name="OptionNo" id="OptionNo" value="0">No</option>
                    <option name="OptionYes" id="OptionYes" value="1">Yes</option>
                </select><br><br>
        <div id="ifYes" style="display:none">
            Please enter your Parent/Guardian's name:<br>
            <input type="text" id="GuardName" name="GuardianName"><br>
            Please enter your Parent/Guardian's phone number:<br>
            <input type="text" id="GuardPhone" name="GuardianNumber"><br>
        </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, but unfortunately this hasn't helped the alerts for completing the registration. The purpose of the Validation function is to give an alert/message after all the required fields have been checked and to ensure that only the necessary fields are validated based on the selector variable.